# fullCalendar: rendering overnight events

Tags: fullcalendar

Consider an event starting Nov 1st 2013 at 20:00 and finishing at 3:00 in the morning (i.e. Nov 2nd, actually). In the month (or week) view, this event occupies 2 days.

Now, is there any way to specify an event as multiday only when that event finishes later than 7am the next day, for example? In other words, is it possible to make fullCalendar render the events for humans that live more at night?

Thank you all for any tips.

PS: (I mean, yes, one could do a workaround displaying the timing of the event only in a qTip using a special slot for the after-midnight hours. But I was wondering whether that is a built-in feature like this.)

Comment: You will get an event rendered in calendar for two days but if you go to dayview you will see that actualy the event will go in second day to 3 am.

Comment: @Henrique C. - I knew that, thanks. However, the question was actually quite different: "_... is there any way to specify an event as multiday only when that event finishes later than 7am the next day, for example? ..._"

Comment: Can you post like an image to show what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this option (for example):

```
nextDayThreshold: '00:01'
```

It means if your event exceeds 00:01 am it will be shown in the next day too

Follow [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/) link to official documentation for more examples

Comment: But this only works for month view. Is there any way to work this for week and day view?